# Internet disconnected, but online games still work?

Tags: connection, gaming

So, I have SuddenLink (don't have a choice of getting anything else for the time being or else I would've ditched this ISP a LONG time ago), and I've never seen this issue with any other ISP. My internet seems to disconnect several times per day for a few minutes at a time. The browser becomes unable to access websites, I can't send/receive messages on chat services like Discord, and streaming services also stop working.

Normally, considering SuddenLink's horrific track record, I wouldn't bat an eye, but what's odd about it is, I'll be connected to a game that requires an online connection, and even though my internet and other services are disconnected, my game still remains connected (as long as I'm already connected and don't log off in the middle of the service interuption).

So what I'd like to know is: One, how is this possible? And two, is there anything happening on my end that's causing this, or is SuddenLink just weird like that?

On a side note, my brother works from home in customer service, and requires a stable internet connection to do his job. Oddly enough, when we're in the midst of an internet outage, if he's in a call with a customer, the call doesn't get dropped. However, I do believe he mentioned there was some degraded quality in the call.

Note again, I've never had this odd issue with ANY other ISP before, and I've been with Roadrunner, Xfinity (and Comcast), and even AT&T U-verse.

Can anyone explain these occurrences to me?

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking aloud here, and without testing its hard to tell. It could be something strange like your connection to DNS servers is broken, which means new attempts to open web pages would fail, windows would also tell you you are disconnected, but already open data connections would continue to work.

Next time it happens, try pinging 8.8.8.8, if that works then its more than likely an issue with name resolution, if it doesn't, then #magicinternet :D

Comment: Well, that's the thing. Windows isn't registering that I'm disconnected when it happens, and if it were simply a matter of not being able to open new web pages, how is that affecting a stream in progress? And if streaming is affected by DNS issues, why isn't online gaming?

Edit: As I'm saying this, I should also mention I have limited knowledge when it comes to networking.

Comment: It is impossible for an OS to reliably detect that it is not connected to the internet. It can detect that it is connected locally. It can detect that it is connected to a particular server. It probably will not detect all problems. However the rest of this answer is valid.

Comment: “if it were simply a matter of not being able to open new web pages, how is that affecting a stream in progress?” — who told you that?

Comment: I have edited my answer, to clarify a few things that are confusing @Shin1201

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing up ideas: The web ≠ The internet.

## Some Possible problems

There could be a problem with:

- A web proxy at your ISP.
- The DNS at your ISP.

To test DNS, in a shell (if on MS-Windows use CMD) type `host web-address` (if on MS-Windows replace `host` with `nslookup`) e.g. `host superuser.com`. If it does not work, then try `host superuser.com 8.8.8.8` or `host superuser.com 1.1.1.1`. If the 2nd works and the first does not, then you ISP's DNS is broken. Reconfigure your machines to use one of the above.

## Background information

- Every new web connection will require a DNS lookup (immediately before the connection is made). If the DNS server goes down, then new connections can not be made.
- Every time you open a new web-page a new connection (or series of them) is made.
- Web pages are loaded via ports 80 and 443. Other internet services go via other ports. Firewalls and proxies may block some ports. A web proxy may be caching traffic on ports 80 and 443. If it goes down then there is no Web traffic, but other internet services will be un-affected.
- While the internet connection and phone, use the same wire to the ISP. From there the service splits. There is a filter at both ends, to separate these services. Just as you have a filter to your phone network within your house, and your router. The ISP has a filter, that connects to the phone network, and to their internet router.